# Add Column based on information from other dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for an answer to a question which I would have solved with for loops.
I have two pandas Dataframes:

```
           ind_1 ind_2 ind_3
   prod_id
A =   a        1    0      0
      a        0    1      0
      b        0    1      0
      c        0    0      1
      a        0    0      1

             a     b     c
B = ind_1   0.1   0.2   0.3
    ind_2   0.4   0.5   0.6
    ind_3   0.7   0.8   0.9
```

I am looking for  a way to solve the following problem with pandas:
I want to map the entries of the dataframe B with a the index and columnnames and create a new column within dataframe A, so the result will look like this:

```
           ind_1 ind_2 ind_3   y 
   prod_id
A =   a        1    0      0  0.1
      a        0    1      0  0.4
      b        0    1      0  0.5
      c        0    0      1  0.9 
      a        0    0      1  0.7
```

Is there a way to not use for loop to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series` in both `DataFrame`s, then filter only `1` values by callable, filter `b` values by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), remove first level of `MultiIndex` and last add new column - it is align by index values of `A`:

```
a = A.T.stack().loc[lambda x: x == 1]
b = B.stack()
b = b[b.index.isin(a.index)].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

A['y'] = b
print (A)
         ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    y
prod_id                          
a            1      0      0  0.1
b            0      1      0  0.5
c            0      0      1  0.9
```

Or use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering, but processing is a bit complicated:

```
a = A.stack()
b = B.stack()

s = (a.to_frame('a')
      .rename_axis((None, None))
      .join(b.swaplevel(1,0)
      .rename('b'))
      .query("a == 1")
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
A['y'] = s['b']
print (A)
         ind_1  ind_2  ind_3    y
prod_id                          
a            1      0      0  0.1
b            0      1      0  0.5
c            0      0      1  0.9
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I get errors in both versions: 
The first one: 
`ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`
The second one: 
`ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names`
I am trying to understand both implementations but I cannot find my errors. Both my dataframes are structured like in my post. Is there a chance you can give me a hint on these?

Comment: @EveEdomenko - It means in your data are duplicated `prod_id` or `id` values or both in one or both DataFrames. Can you check it? Solution working if unique values like in your question. Is possible remove duplicates?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have duplicated `prod_ids`. I have to keep them so I should change my question. I was not sure if I have to keep them.